# Using 'TbButtonColumn' in 'quickdlgs.EJuiDlgsColumn' . for rendering views using dialog box in grid view in Yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii

In my web application I need to use dialog box for the CRUD operations.I am using  'quickdlgs'
yii extension. I am getting the view as a dialog box but not as the grid view which yiistrap uses. I need the views in dialog boxes as the  widgets supplied by yiistrap.
My code for the admin view page.

```
<?php
 $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'id'=>'vegetable-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'code',
        'img_name',
        'is_deleted',
        array(
        'class'=>'ext.quickdlgs.EJuiDlgsColumn' ,
        'deleteConfirmation'=>"js:'Do you really want to delete record with Vegetable name '+$(this).parent().parent().children(':nth-child(2)').text()+'?'",
        'template'=> '{view}{delete}{update}',
        'buttons'=>array
        (
                'view'=>array(
                        'label'=>'ajax dialog view',
                        'viewDialog'=>array('controllerRoute'=> 'view',
                                'actionParams' => array('id'=> '$data->id'),
                                'dialogTitle'  => 'View detail',
                                'hideTitleBar'=>true,
                                'dialogWidth' => 800,
                                'dialogHeight'=>800,
                        ),
                ),
                'update'=>array(

                        'updateDialog'=>array(
                                'controllerRoute' => 'vegetable/update',
                                'actionParams' => array('parentId' => '$data->id'),
                                'dialogTitle' => ' Update Vegetable',
                                'dialogWidth' => 1024,
                                'dialogHeight' => 600,
                        ),
                ),
        ),
),


    ),
));
```

Any body help me how to proceed since I am new to yii framework and I do not have much idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you, Try this on your code

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('update',array('ajaxupdate','act'=>'doUpdate'), array('success'=>'reloadGrid'),array('class'=>'update','confirm'=>'Are
you sure you want to update?')); ?>
```

Comment: where should I add . In the grid view class its not allowing me to echo any content

Answer (score 1):

You want it on the row action, so please try the following code in your update array

```
'update'=>array("click"=>"CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('update',array('ajaxupdate', 'act'=>'doUpdate'‌​), array('success' => 'reloadGrid'),array('confirm'=>'Are you sure you
 want to update?' ) )",
```